# Why does this BSD grep result differ from GNU grep?

Tags: linux, grep, osx, regular-expression, freebsd

My computer is running macOS 10.12.3 and I am using the system-installed `grep` utility with version 2.5.1-FreeBSD.

These are the outputs I get when testing various regexes:

[image: Screenshot]

But if I run these using GNU grep (version 2.25) I get the following:

[image: Screenshot]

GNU's grep looks correct to me and BSD's is incorrect, no? Why do they differ? I don't understand why BSD's grep is matching the "a" when the regex specifies that it must follow the beginning of the line.

Comment: Feel free to report the first behaviour as a bug.

Comment: You'll see that `echo 'bababa' | grep -E '^(a|b)'` is all red. And you'll have the same problem with `-o`. I guess, `grep` looks for multiple matches, but for the second match and over, it applies the regexp to what's on the right of what matched the previous time (so on `anana` on the second time in your case) without passing the REG_NOTBOL flag. See also `echo banana | grep -Eo '^ban|^ana$'`

Comment: @JdeBP, on my OS X, `grep` identifies itself as `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` with the man page referring to GNU only by mentioning "long options provided for compatibility with GNU versions". Also, no copyright notice or mentions of GPL (or FSF). If it has history with the GNU util, it's hard to tell.

Comment: We're demonstrating **how** this is misleading. (-: The `grep` that is discussed in Decade Moon's answer that so many people are thinking is correct identifies as `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` (as can be seen in the bug discussion), has a FSF copyright notice, and is most definitely GNU `grep`. What FreeBSD calls `bsdgrep` is what OpenBSD calls `grep` and is BSD `grep`, with no `--color` option outwith the FreeBSD variant.  That is what identifies as `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`, and ironically is what one person in the bug discussion suggested that FreeBSD switch `grep` to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this might be a bug in FreeBSD's grep. There's a [bug report](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201650) with similar issues.