# grep grouping with wildcards prints whole file without matching

Tags: grep, wildcards

Doing a grouping with grep using parenthesis, and combining that with a wildcard, e.g. `*` or `?`, will print the whole file but does not highlight any matches that *should* have been found.

Example `test.txt`:

```
find this
asdffind this
find this asdf
sadffind thisasdf
(find this)
(find this)?
```

`grep -in "find this" test.txt`:
**find this**
asdf**find this**
**find this** asdf
sadf**find this**asdf
(**find this**)
(**find this**)?

`grep -in "\(find this\)" test.txt`:
**find this**
asdf**find this**
**find this** asdf
sadf**find this**asdf
(**find this**)
(**find this**)?

`grep -in "\(find this\)\?" test.txt`:
**find this**
   find this   <-- why wasn't `find this` matched?
asdffind this   <-- why wasn't `find this` matched?
**find this** asdf
sadffind thisasdf   <-- why wasn't `find this` matched?
(find this)   <-- why wasn't `find this` matched?
(find this)?   <-- why wasn't `find this` matched?

With the `?` it found only the phrases started at beginning of line. This is also true of the `*` character.

I'm trying to apply the `?` wildcard to the *whole phrase*.  Without the parenthesis it would only apply to the last word it is on, yes?
`grep "find this\?"` only applies the `?` to `this`, which is not what I want.

Edit:

I think my problem is I'm trying to treat a "phrase of words" as a single word, which doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Exactly what do you want to match in your example file that your example expressions are not covering? You only want to match the line "find this asdf"?

Comment: This is behaving the way it is supposed to. You are obviously expecting something different but it's hard to explain if you don't tell us what you were expecting. Everything looks fine to me here.

Comment: @MikeDannyboy can you not simply show what is the output that you expect instead of ambiguous statements which confuse rather than clarify.

Comment: Your last command works fine (brings all the results you expect) with gnu grep 2.27 in Debian. I suspect that you use some non gnu grep under Mac Os. People have report various similar bugs about this mac grep : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep

Comment: @don_crissti grep 2.5.1

Comment: @don_crissti Bugs in this grep version is a fact : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352977/why-does-this-bsd-grep-result-differ-from-gnu-grep and also https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201650

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you thought you need to escape parentheses in order to disable grouping when, actually, escaping them is what enables it. For example, to print only those lines matching `(find this)`, you would run:

```
$ grep -in "(find this)" test.txt
5:(find this)
6:(find this)?
```

When you escape the parentheses (`\( \)`), you are telling `grep` not to treat the `(` and `)` as normal characters but as the special "group" delimiters. This, for example, lets you do things like:

```
$ echo "foofoo" | grep -o '\(.oo\)\1'
foofoo
```

That matches any character followed by two Os (`.oo`) but because it is in escaped parentheses, we can now refer to whatever was matched as `\1`, letting us match `foofoo` with `\(.oo\).*\1`.

Same goes for the `?`. Unless it follows a regex wildcard like `.`, that is just a normal character. So, to match the line with `(find this)?` only, you would do:

```
$ grep -in "(find this)?" test.txt
6:(find this)?
```

Comment: I've edited my question, maybe it's more clear?

Comment: @MikeDannyboy not really. You have some misunderstandings so you are using the wrong tools. You need to show us the output you want to see. Telling us you want to apply the `?` to the whole phrase isn't useful if you don't tell us what you expect the `?` to do. In fact, applying it to the phrase is pointless. So, edit your question and show us the output you want to see.

Comment: @MikeDannyboy And also state the `grep` version you are using, and the `OS` this thing is running on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're actually trying to do (your explanations don't make sense), so I'll only answer to explain what the commands you posted do. As noted in comments, it's possible that you've encountered a bug in your old version of grep; try a more recent version (e.g. on a modern Linux distribution or from Homebrew).

Grep searches for lines containing a match for the specified pattern. The output of grep is the whole line, regardless of which part of the line is matched. (The option `-o` changes this.) For example `grep a test.txt` prints all the lines that contain `a`. The whole lines, not just `a`.

In particular, if the pattern can match an empty string, then grep will print all lines. For example, since `\?` is the zero-or-one operator, `grep 'a\?' test.txt` prints all the lines that either contain `a` or contain the empty string. Since all lines contain the empty string, this prints all lines.

Similarly `grep "\(find this\)\?"` prints all the lines that either contain `find this` or the empty string, so it prints all lines. The operator `\?` is applied to the group `find this` (backslash-parentheses delimit a group in the default regex syntax for grep).

Highlighting is applied on top of the line matching behavior. When there are multiple ways to match a line, it's unspecified which part grep will consider to be matching, except that the documentation (as of GNU grep 2.25) states that a non-empty match will be used if possible. I think GNU grep uses the longest match.

Note that operators never applied to “words”. They apply to the previous *character* or *parenthesized group*. For example `find this\?` means “either `find this` or `find thi`” — the `\?` operator applies to the last `s` only. To match either `find` or `find this`, use a group: `find\( this\)\?`.